# Can I change gerrit authentication type from openid to ldap?

Tags: authentication, ldap, openid, gerrit

We in our team are planning to use gerrit. So, to get introduced, I did set up a server, used open-id for authentication and created some test-users and test-projects in it.

Now we are ready to use it. But we actually prefer LDAP for real use.

1. So, can I change my authentication system from open-id from LDAP? What will happen to current users then?
2. I want to clear test projects and changes. How can I do them?
3. Can I complete delete existing gerrit setup and initiate a fresh setup in same machine? (I tried extracting the jar in different folder, but I faced some problems in it)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as my server.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the database (you're not using the H2 database anymore, but some MySQL or PostgreSQL server, don't you?) plus the directory where Gerrit is running (the `-d` parameter, see [docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install.html#init)). Additionally, remove the git repos, if you configured them to be located on a different path.

Then all your data is gone and you can start from scratch.

Comment: I am using H2. By no way, I can read the DB. The gerrit gsql command fails saying I am not authorized. The interface denies me to grant the permission, thought I logged in as administrative user. So, I am thinking to leave the stuff intact, and run the jar with different directory with mysql DB.